# Name of a fictional scientist with fictional publications invented and ‘working’ at an existing British university

Tags: university, personal-name, academic-history

At some British university a fictional professor was invented in the 20th century. He also had is own office and his own (fictional) field of research, in which he published about three papers (in a fictional journal). I read about him a few years ago. I think that he had his own Wikipedia article (English Wikipedia). His publications were cited a few times in real publications.

The persons is similar to Albert Wormstein ([Stewart & Wormstein, 1992](https://doi.org/10.1016/0097-3165(92)90058-3); cf. [Math.SE Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/448078/343349)) or the [Poppleton University](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poppleton_University).

It is not a fictional character in a book or a movie. (Otherwise I would have asked this question on another Stack Exchange site.) But he was invented by the people working at the particular university.

I am looking for the person’s name (fictional), his field of research (fictional), and the university’s name (real).

Comment: Interesting, I had a couple of ideas for the title of the question [now deleted] but it wouldn't match the details of the question

Comment: One of typical approaches is to combine name and last name of well known scientists, in order to make obvious on the first read that the person is fictional. e.g. Isaac Clarke or Sigmund Jung...

(I fallen into same trap as JosephDoggie -- you daniel.neumann might want to rephrase the question)

Comment: @hardyVeles : You mean I should rephrase the title of the post or the question in the body of the post?

Comment: @hardyVeles Is it clearer now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you thinking of [Professor Moriarty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Professor_Moriarty) (he's from a fictional book series, but he did author two works that have been cited in the literature), or one of the three fictional winners of the [first Ig Nobel Prize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ig_Nobel_Prize#History), Josiah S. Carberry, Paul DeFanti, and Thomas Kyle?

Comment: Thanks, it was [Josiah S. Carberry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josiah_S._Carberry) who works in the field of _psychoceramics_ at Brown University in the US (not UK -- I mixed it up). He even has his own ORCID ([0000-0002-1825-0097](http://orcid.org/0000-0002-1825-0097)).